# Having trouble displaying images from API on Flask App

Tags: python, api, flask, jinja2

Cannot figure out how to display an image from this API. So far I am just getting a little "broken image" icon for all. Not sure how I use PIL or os in this situation, since I have my image paths in a list?

```
import constants
import requests
import json
import os
from PIL import Image
from datetime import date
from flask import Flask, request, redirect, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")

@app.route("/epic")
def epic():
    API_KEY = "BCW9Yze09fgybClikOmfseqV0Cc7diObPigF3x6R"
    date = request.args.get("date")
    base_url = f"https://api.nasa.gov/mars-photos/api/v1/rovers/curiosity/photos?earth_date={date}&api_key={API_KEY}"

# converting API response into dict
data = requests.get(base_url).json()

test = []
imgs = []

for idx, img in enumerate(data['photos']):
    test.append({data['photos'][idx]['camera']['full_name']})
    imgs.append({data['photos'][idx]['img_src']})
```

html-

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block content %}
<div id="bod">
    
    Photos from {{ date }}:<br><br>

    <br>{{ test }}<br>

    {% if imgs %}
    <table>
        {% for img in imgs %}
            <tr>
                <td><img src="{{ img }}"/></td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </table>

    {% else %}
        No results.
    {% endif %}    

</div>
{% endblock %}
```

sample of the json I'm working with:

```
{"photos":[{"id":784549,"sol":2979,"camera":{"id":20,"name":"FHAZ","rover_id":5,"full_name":"Front Hazard Avoidance Camera"},"img_src":"https://mars.nasa.gov/msl-raw-images/proj/msl/redops/ods/surface/sol/02979/opgs/edr/fcam/FLB_661957383EDR_F0842044FHAZ00302M_.JPG","earth_date":"2020-12-22","rover":{"id":5,"name":"Curiosity","landing_date":"2012-08-06","launch_date":"2011-11-26","status":"active"}},{"id":784550,"sol":2979,"camera":{"id":20,"name":"FHAZ","rover_id":5,"full_name":"Front Hazard Avoidance Camera"}
```

Comment: What is the URL of an image, and the URL of that image being output in your code? are they the same?

Comment: It actually seems that the first image I print to the console and the first image displayed in the json file are different. However should it still be printing a photo anyway? Image URL prints to console as such : https://mars.nasa.gov/msl-raw-images/msss/02977/mcam/2977ML0155500021104939E01_DXXX.jpg